# Test if file is blank using FileReader

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to add an `else if` to the code block inside my while loop below which tests if the `LandingsData.txt` file is blank. If it is blank, then print `"Starting with an empty system"`

```
    FileReader fr = null;

    try {
        fr = new FileReader("LandingsData.txt");
        
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File not found");
    }

Scanner myFile = new Scanner(fr);
String line;
myFile.useDelimiter(",|\\n");
while (myFile.hasNext()) {
    line = myFile.next();
    if (line.equals("sl")) {
        StrongLanding sl = new StrongLanding();
        sl.setLandingId(Integer.parseInt(myFile.next()));
        sl.setLandingDesc(myFile.next());
        sl.setNumLandings(Integer.parseInt(myFile.next()));
        sl.setCost(Double.parseDouble(myFile.next()));
        landings.add(sl);
    } else if (line.equals("ul")) {
        UltimateLanding ul = new UltimateLanding();
        ul.setLandingId(Integer.parseInt(myFile.next()));
        ul.setLandingDesc(myFile.next());
        ul.setNumLandings(Integer.parseInt(myFile.next()));
        ul.setCost(Double.parseDouble(myFile.next()));
        landings.add(ul);
    } else if (fr.length() == 0) {
        System.out.println("Starting with an empty system");
    }
}
```

I've tried a few different ways with this using `fr.length()` or `fr.count()` but I seem to be receiving the error `The method length() is undefined for the type FileReader`

I've also tried a few different spots outside of the while loop as I thought this might be the issue, but no luck

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Scanner myFile = new Scanner(fr);
String line;
myFile.useDelimiter(",|\\n");
if (!myFile.hasNext()){
    System.out.println("Starting with an empty system");
} else {
    while (myFile.hasNext()) {
        line = myFile.next();
        if (line.equals("sl")) {
            // Do stuff
        } else if (line.equals("ul")) {
            // Do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Call `hasNext()` once before reading the file to see if the file is empty.

Comment: if I use fr.readLine() == null inside the while loop I still get the same undefined error

Comment: instead of checking `.length()` at the end, first check if `fr.readLine() == null` then use the `.equals` cases

Comment: @user16320675 thanks I misread the question. Rewrote a new solution with minimal modification to source code.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if a file is empty using the below code:

```java
File myFile = new file("file.txt");

if(myFile.isEmpty())
{
    System.out.println("Starting with an empty system");
}
```

Use `File` class not `FileReader`.

Or if you need to use `FileReader`, you could do it this way:

```java
// Checking if the first line of the file is empty
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"));     
if (br.readLine() == null) 
{
    System.out.println("No errors, and file empty");
}
```

And do the check before you start your while loop, you compare the first line with two strings **then** you check whether the file is empty or not...